# how to upload a image from frontend with wp_insert_post and also update_post_meta?

Tags: custom-field, attachments, wp-insert-post, wp-load.php, input

I am using cmb2 for frontend form submission with custom post type name 'form'.
But can not upload image with that.
the first step is:

```
    array(
            'name' => 'Image',
            'type' => 'file',
            'id' => '_first_image',
            'options' => array(
                'url' => true, // Hide the text input for the url
            ),
            'text'    => array(
                'add_upload_file_text' => 'Upload your image image', // Change upload button text. Default: "Add or Upload File"
            ),
        ),
```

my form is:

```
 <form method="post" action="" id="form">
        <div class="student-image">
            <label for="student_image">Image</label>
            <input name="image" type="file" id="img" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg">
        </div>

 <input style="color: white;" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_type' => 'form',
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_title' => $_POST['name'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['subject'],
    
);
$query = wp_insert_post( $args, false );
$image = $_POST['image'];
if(query){
         update_post_meta( $query, '_first_image', $image );
  }
}
```

This is my code. I can't upload any image. what can I do for uploading images and what code do I add to complete. and also add to upload only one image.
can any one give me the solution. I am trying other solution but those can't work.